# How can I go to specific time in video using opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv, video

I'm trying to capture the video. If I input 00:00:10, I want to go to that time of video and capture it.

Now, I get the duration of video. And If the duration is same with input time, I stop and capture it. But that takes too much time.

```
int timing = cap.get(CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC);
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function

> bool cv::VideoCapture::set    (   int     propId,
>   double  value 
>   )

with

> propId = CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC //Current position of the video file in milliseconds.

Example:

```
VideoCapture openCVCapture("video1.mp4");
openCVCapture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC,20000)      //jump to 20 sec
openCVCapture >> image;
```

More information is in [Opencv docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#a8c6d8c2d37505b5ca61ffd4bb54e9a7c)